# consider 2 request in a thread group, How to execute the 1request for one time and remaining request as per the thread count

Tags: json, api, jmeter

1. Assume 2 requests in a thread group. Thread count is 100
2. Http sampler A, Http sampler b
3. I have extracted a set of values using JSON extractor and stored in a variable
4. I used the extracted values in request sampler b (added controller for each extracted values)
5. when I try to execute this script both the request ran for 100times
6. So I have added once the only controller for the 1st request. Even though both the request ran for 100times

I want to execute Request A for one time and request B for 100times. How can we achieve this?

Comment: is this homework help or something. or some code puzzle contest? I apologize if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) JMeter Variables are local to the thread (virtual user) so if you use variables from `HTTP Sampler A` in `HTTP Sampler B` you need to execute `HTTP Sampler A` **once per user** which gives you 100 executions.

If you're looking for a way to execute `HTTP Sampler A` only once, no matter how many threads you have:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to your Test Plan and keep threads/loops count as `1`
2. Put your `HTTP Sampler A` under that setUp Thread Group
3. Save each value from JSON Extractor into a **JMeter Property** using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function
4. In your main Thread Group use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to access the values extracted in the setUp Thread Group